# Setting up cassandra identity for asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, cassandra

I bumped into AspNet.Identity.Cassandra. I have also installed the Cassandra driver for .NET. Yet i am finding it difficult to set up my account controller. 
I get lots of errors. Basic of them has to do with instantiating my UserManager.

This is my constructor initialization

```
 public AccountController()
    {
        this.userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new CassandraUserStore<ApplicationUser>(SessionCreator.Create()));
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager { get; set; }
```

I get UserManager underlined with the error

> Error 1   The type 'CassandraIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CassandraIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.

Another error is

> Error 2   The type 'CassandraIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CassandraIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.

Another error is

> Error 3   The non-generic type 'AspNet.Identity.Cassandra.CassandraUserStore' cannot be used with type arguments

Can anyone please help me with setting up the account controller using the cassandra identity package?

Comment: I think you have to provide some code and what errors you get.

Comment: I have added the constructor and the errors i get associated with the constructor. Please review for me

Comment: did you saw examples at [1](https://github.com/LukeTillman/AspNet.Identity.Cassandra/blob/master/examples/CassandraAuthSimpleExample/CassandraAuthSimpleExample/Controllers/AccountController.cs)?  `public AccountController()
{
UserManager = new UserManager<CassandraUser>(new CassandraUserStore<CassandraUser>(SessionCreator.Create()));
}
public UserManager<CassandraUser> UserManager { get; private set; }`

Comment: I get the following error Error 1 The type 'AspNet.Identity.Cassandra.CassandraUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AspNet.Identity.Cassandra.CassandraUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>'